# Virtual table not getting created but regular table works fine in phonegap ,sqlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, mobile-application, full-text-search

I am using eclipse to build phonegap app and have large database to search  when i use command

```
 function populateDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE t_name USING FTS3 ( col1,clo2 );');
```

it is going to errorCB method and not on successCB method,but when i use statement

```
 tx.executeSql('CREATE  TABLE stable ( header,fullcontent,uid)');
```

The table gets created as i can see through sqliteDatabase browser.

When i tried to create virtual table from sqlite3 from command line, virual table command was working and my table also got created.Why virtual table is not getting created though html file

also please tell me where is database created by sqlite3 commandline